# Working with dynamically generated children

Tags: reactjs

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/45826/)

```
   var model = ["abc","b","c"];

var RawEditableField = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    value: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    changeEvent: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>      
          <input type="text" value={this.props.value} onChange={this.props.changeEvent}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});


var Hello = React.createClass({
    createFields(){
    var jsxResult = model.map(this.createField, this);
    return jsxResult;
  },

  handleValueChange(e){
    var inputValue = e.nativeEvent.target.value;
    console.log('handleValueChange', inputValue);
    console.log('handleValueChange', e.nativeEvent.target);
    console.log('handleValueChange', e.currentTarget);
    console.log('handleValueChange', e);
     console.log('handleValueChange', e._targetInst);
    //this.refs.a.props.value = inputValue;//tried hard coding value is readonly
    console.log('refs: ', this.refs);
    //e.nativeEvent.target.value = inputValue;
  },

  handleSave(){
    console.log('gather state of all fields');
  },

  createField(data){
    //console.log('createField data:', data);
    return <RawEditableField key={data} value={data} changeEvent={this.handleValueChange} ref={data} />;
  },

  render: function() {
    var fieldJsx = this.createFields();
    return <div>                    
             {fieldJsx}
             <input type="submit" onClick={this.handleSave} value="Submit" />
           </div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

I want to track the state of dynamically generated children. I don't know how to approach the problem.  See the fiddle for a working example.  I have N# of inputs:

```
<input type="text" key={this.props.keyName} value={this.props.value} onChange={this.props.changeEvent}/>
```

How do I track the state of each one?  Do I need to dynamically add state to the parent object and if yes how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To track the state of children add a ref to each one and grab it off: `this.refs`

```
<input type="text" ref={this.props.keyName} key={this.props.keyName} value={this.props.value} onChange={this.props.changeEvent}/>
```

You can grab that input in a Parent component now by using `this.refs.keyname` substituting the actual value of `keyname` of course.

Here are the React docs on [Refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html)

Comment: This is close.  I'm having difficulty finding the key of the element that triggered the event.  How do I find and use the key to update the value of the text?  If you could modify the fiddle to do this much that would answer my question.

Comment: well if you set the ref to the key, as what I did above, you can just use the ref

Comment: Sorry I tried that and it didn't suit my purpose.  Hard coding the refs is not going to work because I don't know the values of the refs ahead of time.